# Visual feedback for area learning and motion tracking in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I'm getting pretty bad results with Area Learning, the localization takes very long and I have no idea what's happening. Did I map the area enough? Is there enough landmarks? Is the ADF alright? No clue.

Is there any way to provide a visual feedback while doing the actual motion tracking and area learning? I keep seeing it in Google videos but didn't find any way of doing it in the Unity SDK.

I would like something like this in my video overlay: https://youtu.be/NTZZCtmR3OY?t=10m57s

Btw my results in Unity are FAR worse than this demo, sometimes it takes minutes for the device to localize and only at a certain spot in the room, the next minute the very same spot doesn't work again. Quite frustrating. No idea what app the presenter uses, for instance, my ADF Inspector reliably crashes every time I try to load any ADF. (Using Wasat and recently I've deleted and re-installed everything.)

Answer (score 0):

It is not supposed to be so. It should not be that bad, under the normal day light condition. If it is a small area, should be able to localize using ADF within 3-5 seconds. The video showed the usual case -- always like this.

If your kernel is up to date, and you are using the correct development kit. I would recommend you to reach the tango team customer service directly.

```
tango-help@google.com
```

Perhaps it is caused by your device defective. If so, ask for an exchange would solve the problem.